# Xcodebuild command failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcodebuild

> Error:error module map file not found
>   Error:failed to emit precompile header (brdgeheader path with some random number)

Build command failed :-

> PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader normal armv7
>   CompileSwiftSources normal armv7 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler

I have tried lots of things change try headersearchpath, mapmodule path change and lots of thing but none of these work.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687998/xcode-10-archiving-fails-only-on-command-line-xcodebuild

Comment: @faysalAhmed I tried it already but not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The error shows something about swift bridging header. Have you add the bridging header file in your project and define it on Build Settings at Swift Compiler section?

Comment: already added in objective-c bridging header but when it build it added some random number in bridgeheaderfilemame so that's issue.. I don't know that random number automatically added.

Comment: Can you please share the build logs to investigate.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. If you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @PrabhatPankaj [Build log] (HTTP://justpaste.it/5i6p1)

Comment: I couldn't comment to the post because insufficient reputation, sorry for asking clarification at here @WaqarUlHaq

Answer (score 0):

As per your logs :0: error: failed to emit precompiled header

error is coming from precompiled header so this value should be YES from the build systems.

Build Settings-> search for precompiled header and set it to YES.

Check your bridging header path $(SRCROOT)/MyPrefixHeaderFile.pch
It should be $(SRCROOT)/FolderName/MyPrefixHeaderFile.pch